# Как написать условие - если курсор мыши находиться на div с id "nazvanie", то event.stopPropagation?

Tags: javascript

Как написать условие - если курсор мыши находиться на div с id "nazvanie", то event.stopPropagation?

Comment: Так повесте на него событие `mouseenter`

Comment: @Alexander Lonberg  у меня небольшой опыт с js, набираюсь опыта на примерах. Не могли бы вы дать ответ с примером? Пожалуйста.

Comment: Вам уже пора писать вопросы, включающие Ваши (пусть и неудавшиеся) попытки реализации. Пока что вопрос выглядит как "сделайте мне".

Comment: @Igor Салют. вы правы, но, на примерах быстрее понимаешь. Там где я уже знаю/понимаю - пишу/дописываю/переписываю сам. Мне больше прессующие визуальное. js мне нужен для реализации некоторых конструкций с разными вариантами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень кратко

```js
var n = document.getElementById( 'nazvanie' );
var count = 0;
n.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', ( e ) => {
    console.log( 'Мы навели курсор на элемент с надписью - ', e.target.textContent, '. Столько то раз - ', ++count );
    // делаете здесь что хотите с вашим stopPropagation
    e.stopPropagation();
    // ...
} );
```

```html
<div id='nazvanie'>Название</div>
```

Comment: Можете помочь ещё? С новым вопросом, пожалуйста.